# AVD Manager: "no system images installed for this target" with necessitas

Tags: android, qt-creator, qt-necessitas

I'd like to use necessitas to develop a simply app. When I run the app, the emulator starts and everything works fine. But I want it to start on my Android device (Android Version 4.1.1) which requires to use API Level 16.

Now for some reason I cannot create a AVD with the message "no system images installed for this target". The "OK" but turns grey as soon as I select a API Level higher than 13.

[image]

But in the SDK Manager I have selected and installed it I I have seen a corresponding directory.

[image]

I have the same problem for API Levels 14,15 and 17.

Comment: Open your skd manager check if you have installed

    ARM EABI v7a System Image
    Intel x8^ Atom System Image


If not installed check and install

Comment: In necessitas sdk manager I have installed simply everything and there is nothing like ARM EABI v7a System.

Comment: what do you have when you open the sdk manager? can you post the snap shot?

Comment: Well, that is what i already did. the second snap shot shows the sdk manager provided by necessitas. all i have is this. And it works except for the higher api levels.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by updating SDK to the newest one.

1. Run "android-sdk/tools/android" from your necessitas (it should open SDK Manager window)
2. Update "Android SDK Tools"
3. Re-run "android-sdk/tools/android"
4. Install "ARM EABI v7a System Image" for API levels 14,15,17